# Apache CXF bean validation fault details

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, bean-validation

I'm trying to use BeanValidation feature of Apache CXF. And stuck now cause don't have any clue how to handle and parse exceptions thrown by validator.
I have web-service interface:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use=SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface TestWSInterface {
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "helloResponse")
    @Valid
    public Hello.Response hello(@WebParam(name = "helloRequest") @Valid Hello.Request request) throws TestWSException;
}
```

Hello.Request is annotated:

```
@XmlType(name = "HelloRequest")
public static class Request extends Command.Request {

    @NotNull(message = "not null required")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 5, message = "[1..5] characters")
    public String name;
}
```

And following configuration in cfx-servlet.xml:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="testWS" implementor="#test" address="/TestWS">
    <jaxws:features>
        <ref bean="commonValidationFeature"/>
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:endpoint>
<bean id="commonValidationFeature" class="org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationFeature"/>
```

So, then I run my request with SoapUI and pass name containing for example 6 characters, I have following response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Fault occurred while processing.</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So my main question is - How can I catch ConstraintViolationException and extend resulting fault response with detailed messages from annotation constraint? Documentation from [Apache CXF - Bean Validation Feature](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/validationfeature.html) looks not very helpful for me. So I really in need for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am facing the same issue and I fixed it using AbstractSoapInterceptor.
To register your Custom Interceptor you have to add the following annotation to your web service.

```
@OutFaultInterceptors(interceptors = { "com.saqi.config.FaultInterceptor" })
```

After that, you have to write your custom FaultInterceptor as follows.

```
public class FaultInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    public FaultInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.MARSHAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage soapMessage) throws Fault {
        Fault fault = (Fault) soapMessage.getContent(Exception.class);

        if (fault.getCause() != null && fault.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {

            ConstraintViolationException constraintViolationException = (ConstraintViolationException) fault.getCause();

            if (!constraintViolationException.getConstraintViolations().isEmpty()) {
                Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraintViolations = constraintViolationException
                        .getConstraintViolations();

                for (ConstraintViolation constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
                    fault.setMessage(constraintViolation.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will show your ConstraintViolationException messages as follows.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Id should follow the pattern!</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note: I am using cxf version 3.1.6